# Swagger with swag gem - response of an array of multiple complex types

Tags: swagger-2.0, rswag

Swagger docs [say](https://swagger.io/specification/#responseObject) that we can use a complex type object specified as array type as follows:

```
"type": "array",
  "items": {
    "$ref": "#/components/schemas/VeryComplexType"
}
```

But what if you have an array of different complex types (e.g. `country`, `address`, etc.) ? When trying to pass multiple `$ref` as follows:

```
"type": "array",
  "items": {
    "$ref": "#/components/schemas/VeryComplexType-1"
    "$ref": "#/components/schemas/VeryComplexType-2"
    "$ref": "#/components/schemas/VeryComplexType-3"
}
```

raises an error:

```
warning: key :$ref is duplicated and overwritten on line 245
warning: key :$ref is duplicated and overwritten on line 246
```

and it keeps the last one only. How is ti possible to fix that (if it is) ?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

It is available starting from Open API 3.0 and it was discussed at this [issue](https://github.com/OAI/OpenAPI-Specification/issues/57#issuecomment-56224153).

As `rswag` [supports](https://github.com/domaindrivendev/rswag#compatibility) **Swagger 2.0** only, it is not possible.